# Mysterious CUDA cuModuleLoad during long Cycles render session

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting

I am using Blender's python interface to render many thousands of small images for a machine-learning dataset and I'm running into a strange problem that I'm wondering if someone can help me with:

I start the program and it renders images fine, about 1 every second. Around the 1000th image, the program throws a cuModuleLoad error and just keeps looping over this error. The machine hasn't run out of memory and nothing else seems to be amiss. It seems that it suddenly can't find `kernel_sm_61.cubin` which **definitely is still there**. I'm pretty confused by this.

Here is what the console output looks like during a successful render:

```
Rendering retries 0
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
Fra:1 Mem:3592.41M (0.00M, Peak 3594.56M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
Fra:1 Mem:3592.41M (0.00M, Peak 3594.56M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Shadowbuffers
Fra:1 Mem:3592.41M (0.00M, Peak 3594.56M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. preparing
Fra:1 Mem:3597.59M (0.00M, Peak 3597.59M) | Time:00:00.01 | Raytree.. building
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Raytree finished
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Creating Environment maps
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Caching Point Densities
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Loading voxel datasets
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Volume preprocessing
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3597.32M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3597.81M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.07 | Scene, Part 1-1
Fra:1 Mem:3587.10M (0.00M, Peak 3605.43M) | Time:00:00.08 | Sce: Scene Ve:39082 Fa:37770 La:1
Saved: '/tmp/tmpmlehxthv.png'
 Time: 00:00.08 (Saving: 00:00.00)

Fra:1 Mem:3587.29M (0.00M, Peak 3587.43M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Ground
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Empty
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Area
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Back
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Fill
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Key
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Camera
Fra:1 Mem:3587.35M (0.00M, Peak 3587.59M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | SmoothCube_v2_0
Fra:1 Mem:3587.66M (0.00M, Peak 3588.03M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | SmoothCylinder_0
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Initializing
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Waiting for render to start
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Scene
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Shaders
Fra:1 Mem:3591.57M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Background
Fra:1 Mem:3591.57M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Camera
Fra:1 Mem:3591.57M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Meshes Flags
Fra:1 Mem:3591.57M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Objects
Fra:1 Mem:3591.57M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Objects | Copying Transformations to device
Fra:1 Mem:3591.58M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Objects | Applying Static Transformations
Fra:1 Mem:3591.58M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Meshes
Fra:1 Mem:3592.72M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Mesh | Computing attributes
Fra:1 Mem:3593.26M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.11 | Mem:0.19M, Peak:0.19M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Attributes to device
Fra:1 Mem:3593.26M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.11 | Mem:0.73M, Peak:0.73M | Scene, Render$
ayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building
Fra:1 Mem:3593.26M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.11 | Mem:0.73M, Peak:0.73M | Scene, Render$
ayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building BVH
Fra:1 Mem:3597.54M (0.00M, Peak 3597.54M) | Time:00:00.13 | Mem:0.73M, Peak:0.73M | Scene, Render$
ayer | Updating Scene BVH | Packing BVH triangles and strands
Fra:1 Mem:3601.54M (0.00M, Peak 3601.54M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:0.73M, Peak:0.73M | Scene, Render$
ayer | Updating Scene BVH | Packing BVH nodes
Fra:1 Mem:3599.35M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:0.73M, Peak:0.73M | Scene, Render$
ayer | Updating Scene BVH | Copying BVH to device
Fra:1 Mem:3599.63M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:6.82M, Peak:6.82M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Mesh | Computing normals
Fra:1 Mem:3602.26M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:6.82M, Peak:6.82M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Mesh to device
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Objects Flags
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Images
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Camera Volume
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Hair Systems
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Hair settings | Copying Hair settings to device
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.45M, Peak:9.45M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Lookup Tables
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.70M, Peak:9.70M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Lights
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.14 | Mem:9.70M, Peak:9.70M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Lights | Computing distribution
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.70M, Peak:9.70M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Particle Systems
Fra:1 Mem:3601.97M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.70M, Peak:9.70M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Particle Systems | Copying Particles to device
Fra:1 Mem:3601.98M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.70M, Peak:9.70M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Integrator
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.73M, Peak:9.73M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Film
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.73M, Peak:9.73M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Lookup Tables
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.74M, Peak:9.74M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Baking
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.74M, Peak:9.74M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Updating Device | Writing constant memory
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3602.78M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:9.74M, Peak:9.74M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Path Tracing Tile 0/1, Sample 0/128
Fra:1 Mem:3602.89M (0.00M, Peak 3603.38M) | Time:00:00.15 | Mem:10.62M, Peak:10.62M | Scene, Rende
rLayer | Path Tracing Tile 1/1, Sample 0/128
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3603.77M) | Time:00:00.40 | Mem:9.74M, Peak:10.62M | Scene, Render
Layer | Path Tracing Tile 1/1, Sample 128/128
Fra:1 Mem:3602.01M (0.00M, Peak 3603.77M) | Time:00:00.40 | Mem:9.74M, Peak:10.62M | Scene, Render
Layer | Finished
Fra:1 Mem:3587.12M (0.00M, Peak 3603.77M) | Time:00:00.49 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '../output/images/fd_single_scenes_two_obj_TESTING/sample_025975.png'
 Time: 00:00.50 (Saving: 00:00.00)
```

And here is what the console output looks like when it hangs up:

```
Rendering retries 0
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
Rendering retries 1
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
Rendering retries 2
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
convertViewVec: called in an invalid context
Fra:1 Mem:3597.26M (0.00M, Peak 3597.26M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
Fra:1 Mem:3601.20M (0.00M, Peak 3602.18M) | Time:00:00.00 | Preparing Scene data
Fra:1 Mem:3601.20M (0.00M, Peak 3602.18M) | Time:00:00.00 | Creating Shadowbuffers
Fra:1 Mem:3601.20M (0.00M, Peak 3602.18M) | Time:00:00.00 | Raytree.. preparing
Fra:1 Mem:3605.47M (0.00M, Peak 3605.47M) | Time:00:00.01 | Raytree.. building
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Raytree finished
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Creating Environment maps
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Caching Point Densities
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Loading voxel datasets
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Volume preprocessing
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3605.23M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.06 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Fra:1 Mem:3605.72M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.08 | Scene, Part 1-1
Fra:1 Mem:3596.73M (0.00M, Peak 3611.91M) | Time:00:00.08 | Sce: Scene Ve:30724 Fa:31121 La:1
Saved: '/tmp/tmpgp58jln8.png'
 Time: 00:00.08 (Saving: 00:00.00)

Fra:1 Mem:3596.93M (0.00M, Peak 3597.06M) | Time:00:00.06 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Ground
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Empty
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Area
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Back
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Fill
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Lamp_Key
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Camera
Fra:1 Mem:3596.99M (0.00M, Peak 3597.23M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Sphere_0
Fra:1 Mem:3598.25M (0.00M, Peak 3599.75M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Synchronizing object | Sphere_1
Fra:1 Mem:3599.51M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Initializing
Fra:1 Mem:3599.51M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found

Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions:
http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Failed loading CUDA kernel /opt/blender/2.78/scripts/addons/cycles/lib/kernel_sm_61.cubin.
Fra:1 Mem:3599.51M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Error | CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Fra:1 Mem:3599.51M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Waiting for render to start
Fra:1 Mem:3599.51M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.07 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Cancel | CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Fra:1 Mem:3596.76M (0.00M, Peak 3601.01M) | Time:00:00.13 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
Error: CUDA error at cuModuleLoad: File not found
```

The "rendering retries" are part of my script, based on a check for mesh intersections and occlusion in the scene. I thought I was handling them correctly, and have verified that a retry alone does not seem to be the culprit -- at least 100 of the first 1000 successful renders had one or more retries.

The difference seems to be that under successful renders it moves on from "loading render kernels"

```
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.08 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
Fra:1 Mem:3590.98M (0.00M, Peak 3594.07M) | Time:00:00.10 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, RenderL
ayer | Waiting for render to start
```

But this is where the hang-up is when there's an error.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on?